# How does reduceByKey work

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing some work with Scala and spark - beginner programmer and poster- the goal is to map each request (line) to a pair (userid, 1) then sum the hits.

Can anyone explain in more detail what is happening on the 1st and 3rd line and **what the `=>`   in: `line => line.split`**  means?

Please excuse any errors in my post formatting as I am new to this website.

```
val userreqs = logs.map(line => line.split(' ')).
   map(words => (words(2),1)).
   reduceByKey((v1,v2) => v1 + v2)
```

Comment: I think `Can anyone explain in more detail what is happening on the 1st and 3rd line and what the => in: line => line.split means?` makes it different.

Answer (score 4):

considering the below hypothetical log

```
trans_id amount  user_id
  1       100     A001
  2       200     A002
  3       300     A001
  4       200     A003
```

this how the data is processed in spark for each operation performed on the logs.

```
logs                            // RDD("1 100 A001","2 200 A002", "3 300 A001", "3 200 A003")
.map(line => line.split(' '))   // RDD(Array(1,100,A001),Array(2,200,A002),Array(3,300,A001), Array(4,200,A003))
.map(words => (words(2),1))     // RDD((A001,1), (A002,1), (A001,1), (A003,1))
.reduceByKey((v1,v2) => v1+v2)  // RDD(A001,2),A(A002,1),A(`003,1))
```

- `line.split(' ')` splits a string into Array of String. "Hello World" => Array("Hello", "World")
- `reduceByKey(_+_)` run a reduce operation grouping data by key. in this case its adds all the values of key.  In the above example there were two occurences for the user-key A001 and the value associated with each of those key was 1. This is now reduced to value 2 using the additive function (`_ + _`) provided in the reduceByKey method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to learn Spark and `reduceByKey` is to read the official documentation of [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@reduceByKey(func:(V,V)=%3EV):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]) that says:

> **reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]** Merge the values for each key using an associative and commutative reduce function.

So it basically takes all the values per key and sums them together to a value that is a sum of all the values per key.

Now, you may be asking yourself:

> What is the key?

The key to understand the key (*pun intended*) is to see how keys are generated and that's the role of the line

```
map(words => (words(2),1)).
```

This is where you take `words` and destructure it into a pair of **key** and `1`.

This is a classic map-reduce algorithm where you give `1` to all keys to reduce them in the following step.

In the end, after this `map` you'll have a series of key-value pairs as follows:

```
(hello, 1)
(world, 1)
(nice, 1)
(to, 1)
(see, 1)
(you, 1)
(again, 1)
(again, 1)
```

I repeated the last `(again, 1)` pair on purpose to show you that pairs can occur multiple times.

The series is created using `RDD.map` operator that takes a function that splits a single line and tokenize it into words.

```
logs.map(line => line.split(' ')).
```

It reads:

> For every `line` in `logs`, split the `line` into tokens using  (space) as separator.

I'd change this line to use a regex like `\\s+` so any white character would get considered part of a separator.

Comment: You don't think that it's a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184058/how-does-reducebykey-work ?

Comment: Yeah. Think so. But the `split` function makes it a bit different so there's some gap.

Answer (score 0):

`line.split(' ')` splits each line with the space which returns an array of string

For example:
`"hello spark scala".split(' ')` gives `[hello, spark, scala]`

```
`reduceByKey((v1,v2) => v1 + v2)`  is equivalent to `reduceByKey(_ + _)`
```

Here is how reduceByKey works https://i.stack.imgur.com/igmG3.gif and http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-reducebykey-example/

For the same key it keeps adding all the values.

Hope this helped!